# nested ng-repeat with open particular index with respect to repeated data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Every time the toggle is clicked, all payments are getting replaced with new payments. My problem is how to maintain the payments of a particular index of every click and show at respective index. please help me out

> here is my html

```
            <tbody data-ng-repeat="invoice in relatedInvoices>
                <tr>
                    <td class="td-bottom-border">
                            {{invoice.PayableCurrencyCode}} {{invoice.PayablePaidAmount | number: 2}}<br />
                            <small>
                                <a data-ng-click="isOpenPayablePayments[$index] = !isOpenPayablePayments[$index]; togglePayablePayments(invoice.PayableInvoiceId)">Paid</a>
                            </small>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr data-ng-show="isOpenPayablePayments[$index]">
                    <td>
                        <table>
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Transaction Id</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr data-ng-repeat="payment in payablePayments">
                                    <td>{{payment.TransactionId}}</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
```

> Here is my javascript

```
    var getPayments = function (invoiceId) {
        paymentService.getPayments(invoiceId).then(function (paymentsResponse) {
            return paymentsResponse.data;
        });
    };

    $scope.togglePayablePayments = function(invoiceId) {
        $scope.payablePayments = getPayments(invoiceId);
    };
```

Comment: Can you provide a plunker for this? No wonder you get new payments, you are calling getPayments every time. What do you mean by "maintain"? It is unclear to me what you want to achieve. Also where is relatedInvoices coming from?

Comment: Do you still have the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want to have "payablePayments" for every invoice.

This is working: http://plnkr.co/edit/cj3jxZ?p=info

Try something like

```
// init at beginning
$scope.payablePayments = [];

$scope.togglePayablePayments = function(invoiceId) {
    $scope.payablePayments[invoiceId] = getPayments(invoiceId);
};
```

and then

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="payment in payablePayments[invoice.PayableInvoiceId]">
```

Otherwise you overwrite the object for the preceding invoice.

Comment: thank q for your response. please check the plunkr for my issue http://plnkr.co/edit/omBL2czm9fRBEVIeQUyD?p=preview

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/cj3jxZ?p=info This is a working fork of your plunker. Please consider marking the answer as correct if your issue is solved.